# the page is not loading after modifying while debugging in firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox

A gridview contains edit link. On clicking edit link, the details of that row are loaded to the textboxes and are modified and saved. After saving, I am checking whether the session id is null or not. If null, then the login page should be loaded. While debugging in chrome, it is working properly. But, while debugging in Firefox, it is loading login page. I have checked by setting break point. The value is not null. I am not able to find out where the id is becoming null.

```
if (lValid)
    {
        insertContact();
        try
        {
            cCode = getContactQuery.saveContactTble(Global.getVK_MaintainConnection, "uspContactIns", getContactStruct, nAdding);
            if (cCode == "-1" || cCode == "-2")
            {
                DisplayMsg("Error in saving. Try Again...");
                lValid = false;
            }

            if (lValid)
            {
                lblError.Text = "Record Successfully Saved.";
                lblError.Visible = true;
                pnlEdit.Visible = false;
                lValid = true;
                if (cIdM == null)
                {
                    LoadGrid();
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('ContactMast.aspx','_Parent')", true);
                    LoadGrid();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Error in saving. Try Again...";
                lblError.Visible = true;
                lValid = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error in saving. Try Again...";
            lblError.Visible = true;
        }
```

client side code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<% if(this.Session["Id"] == null) 
{%>
window.parent.location="Login.aspx";
<%}
%>
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced

```
"window.open('ContactMast.aspx','_Parent')"
```

with

```
"window.open('Contact.aspx?RequestId=" + cRequestId + "','frame_c')", true);
```